# shutdown or suspend in parallels

Tags: parallels-desktop

I use Windows 8.1 in Parallels. Daily in evening for 5 hours, I open my C++ primer book (PDF) and code in Visual Studio. I feel little lazy in closing the book and Visual Studio everyday. Should I suspend Windows for resuming it from that very place next day? Or suspending Windows has some negative sides on machine/Parallels/Windows? Please let me know if there are down sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suspending a VM should not have a negative impact on the guest OS. As far as the OS is concerned it shouldn't be much different than going to sleep.